# Problem with shaded regions in a square

Tags: geometry, area

The sides of a square are 16 cm in length. The midpoints of the sides of this square are joined to form a new square and four triangles (diagram 1). The process is repeated twice as shown in the diagrams 2 and 3.

[image: squares]

Consider an initial square of side length $$
Kcm\,.
$$ The process described above is repeated indefinitely. The total area of shaded regions is
$$
Kcm^{2}\,.
$$

What is the value of K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial square of side-length $k$ cm has an area of $k^2$ cm, and you can see that $A_1=k^2/8$. Looking at the diagram you can see that $A_{n+1}=A_n/2$. This is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with $a=k^2/8$ and $r=1/2$. So the sum of all the areas is $$\frac{k^2/8}{1-1/2}=\frac{k^2}{4}$$

Comment: I understood the concept of geotric series applied to this case, however I don't understand why is $A_1=k^2/8$

Comment: @AndréEnriqueBrañezQuiroz Well lets find the area of $A_1$. The area of the triangle is $1/2\times base\times height$. The height is $k/2$ and the length of the base is also $k/2$ because the length of a corner to a midpoint is half the side. So the area is $1/2\times k/2\times k/2$